# Explaining dc-dc boost converter circuit

Tags: mosfet, diodes, dc-dc-converter

I’m trying to make very fast charger for my capacitor, to do so I am making my own circuit however, I saw this video on youtube:

https://youtu.be/ug82NsxXL94

and thinking of making this circuit. Fortunately he shared the schematic.

[image]

I see it is very basic boost converter, the only thing I was doubt about is the 10 kΩ resistor won't be enough to discharge the gate of MOSFET as well the internal structure won't allow this perfectly, but I think I will try to use 10 kΩ, if it is not ok I will use pull down on the gate but after watching the video I realized it could work.

Could any one explain the circuit and add his comment on it for sharing more info?

Comment: Given the voltage rating on the cap it looks like you're aiming for 100's of volts -- do a search on photoflash chargers.  Even though they're named "photoflash", they work for any use case where you're interested in charging up a cap to multiple hundreds of volts.  The recent ones have all the bells and whistles you might desire, and sample circuits to boot.

Comment: That gate resistor looks like 10R=10Ohm and not 10K=10kOhm.  Looking at the linked video in full screen mode the "R" in the schematic is clearer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just some basic bullet points:

- A 555 timer is almost electronic shorthand for "I don't know what I'm doing".  They can be used appropriately, but it's been my experience that the number of use cases is vanishingly small.  (In my decade+ of experience, I've designed-in maybe... three of them?)
- General architecture is a single-stage boost with extremely high ratio.  This requires prohibitively large MOSFET and bypass capacitors.  A transformer (flyback) or tapped inductor (hybrid) is preferred.
- There is no current sense on the inductor or MOSFET.
- In fact, there is no control at all, the 555 is simply an open-loop free running oscillator.
- I mean, it does eventually stop if the output reaches setpoint (gated by the comparator), but startup and charge are completely uncontrolled otherwise.
- Personally, I insist upon either peak or average current mode controls in design review, with constant-on/off-time controls being an "acceptable" 2nd.  (With an open-loop oscillator, and no current sense, this is neither, of course.)
- Likely, this operates (or, well, *can* operate) by the output charging far enough that the ~53% duty cycle gives DCM (discontinuous current mode) operation, which limits switch/inductor current to \$I_\textrm{pk} = \dfrac{V_\textrm{in} t_\textrm{on}}{L}\$, or... 57A.  Hrm, well, that's not very good actually, is it.  It will definitely be lower due to MOSFET R<sub>DS(on)</sub>, but it will also rise to the maximum level much faster due to saturation of the 20A (combined rating) inductor.
- The only control (to speak of) is burst hysteretic mode, i.e. a comparator gating the oscillator.  This isn't bad in and of itself, but the comparator lacks positive feedback (to implement a known amount of hysteresis), and the voltage regulation will be very noisy (making this undesirable as a power supply, but this at least doesn't matter for a capacitor charger).

The gate drive doesn't actually factor into these at all, actually.  While the NE555 (or whatever version they chose..) is a terrible gate driver (it's only 200mA output, and saturates poorly towards either supply -- expect V<sub>GS(on)</sub> about 10V and V<sub>GS(off)</sub> about 0.5V), the switching frequency (a few kHz!) is low enough not to mind, and the slow turn-off probably saves the MOSFET from avalanche due to loop inductance (between MOSFET, output diode, and output filter cap).  It does of course dissipate a lot of switching loss during charge, but it dissipates a lot anyway due to the poorly chosen frequency and inductance.

This review contains a lot of negatives, but mind that many of them are straightforward fixes.  Whether that counts as dumping on the original circuit, is a matter of opinion I suppose -- small changes are simple enough, but with each change, new resembles the old less and less, and to the extent that an improved circuit has significant differences from the original, it might be said to be a completely different design, which is equivalent to saying the original circuit is particularly poor.  Put another way: how negative you choose to read this, I suppose depends on how fundamental you consider these elements to the essence of the circuit.

And, mind the nature of the design review.  We don't have a list of specifications to check off here, so the positives are simply the negative space, everything not covered by the negatives.  (Given an exhaustive list of negatives, that is; the above is hardly exhaustive, but I'd say it's the most important parts, and the rest are either speculative (undefined) or likely too inconsequential to be actionable.)  It *will* operate at nominal (12-24V) supply (again, to the extent it operates at all), and it will charge a capacitor "quickly" (for some value of "quick"), to "high" voltages (for some value of "high").  It could be much better at these things (e.g. UVLO to set Vin(min) accurately; better output stage, inductor and Fsw, and controller, to vastly increase efficiency; etc.), but in lieu of a specification, there isn't really any reason to bring attention to these, either.

I could also add critiques like EMI emissions or surge immunity (making some assumptions about application, like whether it needs to endure automotive load dump), but again, without any context, what it's connected to, what it might affect and what it might be affected by; and without a PCB layout let alone mechanical assembly, these are fairly superfluous.

As for improvements -- like I said, it's really not all that much, at least conceptually.  For example, we could change inductor to transformer; change MOSFET and diode (MOSFET can be, say, 100V 50A; diode can be 1200V 4A SiC); change to a UC3843 controller (or for something newer, LM3481); and just generally design the component values properly (setting Fsw and primary inductance appropriate for the component ratings).  Maybe a snubber on the MOSFET and/or diode; which somewhat goes along with other EMI tweaks, which again being undefined, isn't worth going into much detail.  For which we probably want an input and output filter, too; but of what type and values, we would require a specification to determine.

Comment: thanks tim for your useful info on this topic, i will do more research and confirm your explaining, i see you do not recommend 555 at all although i think it is a magic easy component to be use, but i will consider this with my researches and back to you, maybe something like UC3845 do the work!

Comment: A 555 isn't really a "magic" component (though Forrest M. Mims III's book makes it seem close!), it's a great starter component for introductory electronic circuits like "press a button and the LED turns on for three seconds" and the internal operation is a wonderful intro to circuit analysis.  But usually if you need a timer or an oscillator, it's part of something else, and the same functionality can be included with additional useful or critical functionality by using something less monolithic.

Comment: The pot allows the output voltage to be adjusted between about 200 V and about 1000 V.  That's way too much for a 600 V MOSFET.

Comment: @tim Williams why you think transformer is better than inductor?, both will do the work but inductor is simple i want the circuit to be simple

Comment: @Tito The high ratio requires tremendous voltage at the transistor, tremendous peak current at the diode, a short discharge pulse (resulting in high core losses), and other minor disadvantages. A transformer improves all of these.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to what @TimWilliams has already said, it looks like you're aiming for hundreds of volts from a 12 V source.

Input-to-output ratios of more than about 5x start to be difficult to get good performance out of a standard boost converter, and more than about 10x are pretty unreasonable. For a step-up ratio that high, I would suggest you look at a flyback topology, or another transformer-coupled topology like a forward converter. These let you take advantage of a transformer to step up the voltage much higher with much less trouble than a conventional boost converter.

Comment: Flyback topology or forward converter will gives this high voltage even much more but with low current, i consider more current so charge capacitor fast

Comment: @Tito A boost converter like you have here will also reduce current.

Comment: but it charge the cap 1500uf in less than 2 sec, can not expect the tranformer would do that, why you prefer transformer over inductor

Comment: @Tito I don't see why you think a transformer couldn't do that. And I prefer a transformer because it allows you to get higher voltages more easily and more efficiently than just using an inductor.